# The review link is oddly aligned

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar

The review link, compared to the help dropdown, is not well aligned. Should probably align the 2 of them more properly.

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? Looks fine in Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m.

Comment: Firefox 25.0.1 under ubuntu but looks like there's already a question on it.

Comment: A fix for this is rolling out shortly.